# Updating android market version previously on market

Tags: android

I want to ask if is it ok that i update already posted version on android market. Like i have version 5.0 and 4.0 on android market. If i want to remove 5.0 from android market and make changes to it and post back the 5.0 version. Is there any implications to that. Is there any problem with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the version no to something great than existing version no. This is required so that android market client knows that a new version is available and it notifies the user to update the app.